# How to combine OR linear inequality with absolute value

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

I have `x < -10 OR x > 15`

How do I turn it into a **single** inequality using an absolute value? 
Like `a < |x+b|`. What are the rules? I'm not sure if it is right, but I'm expecting an answer something like how factoring quadratic trinomials would be explained, which is really straightforward.

Thank you

Comment: The way I think about this is that $x$ is at most ___ away from the midpoint of $-10$ and $15$ (remember that absolute value tells distance).

Comment: Try doing some examples -- which $x$ satisfy $|x-2| < 1$?

Comment: So it could always be in the form $a<|x-b|$?

Comment: @andybenji btw, your example is AND inequality

Comment: My example wasn't intended to be the exact same as your question. Try out some examples, and see if all the inequalities you can think of can be written in that form.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq] to familiarise yourself with some of our common practices. In addition, [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/8348) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good.

Comment: @Joao I don't think that comment belongs here. Im not new to SE.

Comment: Oh. Sorry. That's a mistake on my part, when you get to 500 rep they make you review "new" user's first posts. Since this was your first post on MSE, I assumed you were new. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** You can use the distance from midpoint argument, or use quadratics:$$x < -10 \text{ OR } x> 15 \iff (x+10)(15-x) < 0 \\ \iff (x-\tfrac52)^2> \tfrac{625}4 \iff |x - \tfrac52| > \tfrac{25}2$$